# Error in sql with rounding

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, rounding

I have a very weird problem with SQL. I have a cell with a number 22, when I want to round it, the result is incorrect.

If I try with the number instead of the cell, the code works well.

```
select Mora2, round(Mora2/30,0)*30, mora2+1, 
round((mora2+1)/30,0)*30, round(convert(float,mora2)/30,0)*30
from Trimestre
```

The result of that is

```
Mora2   (No column name)    (No column name)    (No column name)    (No column name)

 22         30                  23                  30                  30
```

If i try with the number, the code works well.

```
 select round(22/30,0)*30 as Mora2

 Mora2
 0
```

Why can be possible that?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the data type of Mora2? The second example is integers, you'll get a different result if you do 22.0 / 30

Comment: Hi James! The data type is float! Besides, I have 28573 registers, but only 866 with that kind of error! Do you know why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `CAST(Mora2 AS INT)` whenever you're using it to strip off the decimal portion and ensure integer division.

When either the numerator or denominator is not an integer, the result of the division will have decimal places.  So `22.0/30` = `0.733333`  while `22/30` = `0`

Comment: Yes! It is like you say! With the int the problem is solved. The weird thing that I don't understand is that I have 28573 registers (all like float) with similar numbers, and only 866 have that problem!